# Trouble tracking down a Bus Error/Seg Fault in C++ and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, segmentation-fault, bus-error

I have a program that processes [neural spike data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_potential) that is broadcast in UDP packets on a local network.

My current program has two threads a UI thread and a worker thread.  The worker thread simply listens for data packets, parses them and makes them available to the UI thread for display and processing. My current implementation works just fine. However for a variety of reasons I'm trying to re-write the program in C++ using an Object Oriented approach.

The current working program initialized the 2nd thread with:

```
pthread_t netThread;
net = NetCom::initUdpRx(host,port);
pthread_create(&netThread, NULL, getNetSpike, (void *)NULL);
```

Here is the `getNetSpike` function that is called by the new thread:

```
void *getNetSpike(void *ptr){
    while(true)
    {
        spike_net_t s;
        NetCom::rxSpike(net, &s);
        spikeBuff[writeIdx] = s;
        writeIdx = incrementIdx(writeIdx);
        nSpikes+=1;
        totalSpikesRead++;
    }
}
```

Now in my new OO version of the program I setup the 2nd thread in much the same way:

```
void SpikePlot::initNetworkRxThread(){
    pthread_t netThread;
    net = NetCom::initUdpRx(host,port);
    pthread_create(&netThread, NULL, networkThreadFunc, this);
}
```

However, because `pthead_create` takes a pointer to a void function and not a pointer to an object's member method I needed to create this simple function that wraps the `SpikePlot.getNetworSpikePacket()` method

```
void *networkThreadFunc(void *ptr){
        SpikePlot *sp = reinterpret_cast<SpikePlot *>(ptr);

    while(true)
    {
        sp->getNetworkSpikePacket();
    }
}
```

Which then calls the `getNetworkSpikePacket()` method:

```
void SpikePlot::getNetworkSpikePacket(){

    spike_net_t s;
    NetCom::rxSpike(net, &s);
    spikeBuff[writeIdx] = s;  // <--- SegFault/BusError occurs on this line
    writeIdx = incrementIdx(writeIdx);
    nSpikes+=1;
    totalSpikesRead++; 
}
```

The code for the two implementations is nearly identical but the 2nd implementation (OO version) crashes with a SegFault or BusError after the first packet that is read. Using `printf` I've narrowed down which line is causing the error:

```
spikeBuff[writeIdx] = s;
```

and for the life of me I can't figure out why its causing my program to crash.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**: 
I define `spikeBuff` as a private member of the class:

```
class SpikePlot{
private:
    static int const MAX_SPIKE_BUFF_SIZE = 50;
    spike_net_t spikeBuff[MAX_SPIKE_BUFF_SIZE];
       ....
}
```

Then in the SpikePlot constructor I call:

```
bzero(&spikeBuff, sizeof(spikeBuff));
```

and set:

```
writeIdx =0;
```

**Update 2**: Ok something really weird is going on with my index variables. To test their sanity I changed `getNetworkSpikePacket` to:

```
void TetrodePlot::getNetworkSpikePacket(){
    printf("Before:writeIdx:%d nspikes:%d totSpike:%d\n", writeIdx, nSpikes, totalSpikesRead);

    spike_net_t s;
    NetCom::rxSpike(net, &s);
//  spikeBuff[writeIdx] = s;
    writeIdx++;// = incrementIdx(writeIdx);
//  if (writeIdx>=MAX_SPIKE_BUFF_SIZE)
        // writeIdx = 0;
    nSpikes += 1;
    totalSpikesRead += 1; 
    printf("After:writeIdx:%d nspikes:%d totSpike:%d\n\n", writeIdx, nSpikes, totalSpikesRead);
}
```

And I get the following output to the console:

```
Before:writeIdx:0 nspikes:0 totSpike:0
After:writeIdx:1 nspikes:32763 totSpike:2053729378

Before:writeIdx:1 nspikes:32763 totSpike:2053729378
After:writeIdx:1 nspikes:0 totSpike:1

Before:writeIdx:1 nspikes:0 totSpike:1
After:writeIdx:32768 nspikes:32768 totSpike:260289889

Before:writeIdx:32768 nspikes:32768 totSpike:260289889
After:writeIdx:32768 nspikes:32768 totSpike:260289890
```

This method is the **only** method where I update their values (besides the constructor where I set them to 0). All other uses of these variables are read only.

Comment: What and where is the definition of spikeBuff?

Comment: Where is `writeIdx` initialized and what does `incrementIdx` look like?

Comment: Next try: check the value of writeIdx before the failing access. If something went wrong, it might be negative or a huge positive number.

Comment: How about `incrementIdx()`? And where is `writeIdx` declared? Is it a global?

Comment: @BjoernD, I've tried printing out writeIdx and setting it to 0 right before the failure line, and its always at the correct value.

Comment: @DavidHammen incrementIdx() is simply (i++)%MAX_SPIKE_BUFF_SIZE

Comment: Please provide the full header file for the members of SpikePlot.

Comment: Can you put the while(true) loop in getNetworkSpikePacket as it was in the non-c++ version?  I'm curious to see if that makes a difference in the variables you're watching in Update 2.  This also seems to be a better fit for what you're trying to do.  Why was it moved into the wrapper in the c++ version in the first place?  Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be wrong but....

You seemed to move the wait loop logic out of the method and into the static wrapper.  With nothing holding the worker thread open, perhaps that thread terminates after the first time you wait for a UDP packet, so second time around, sp in the static method now points to an instance that has left scope and been destructed?

Can you try to assert(sp) in the wrapper before trying to call its getNetworkSpikePacket()?

Comment: not the exact problem but it pointed me in the right direction to solve the bug.

Comment: What was the exact problem?  Want to edit the question or the answer and show what was going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go on a limb here and say all your problems are caused by the zeroing out of the spike_net_t array.

In C++ you *must not* zero out objects with non-*[insert word for 'struct-like' here]* members. i.e. if you have an object that contains a complex object (a std string, a vector, etc. etc.) you cannot zero it out, as this destroys the initialization of the object done in the constructor.

Comment: ok, I didn't think I needed to do that but I added it when things weren't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allocating the `spikeBuff` array anywhere then make sure you are allocating sufficient storage so `writeIdx` is not an out-of-bounds index.

I'd also check that `initNetworkRxThread` is being called on an allocated instance of `spikePlot` object (and not on just a declared pointer).

Comment: and presumably you've printed out the value of writeIdx just before the crash and it's within the array bounds. Right ?

Comment: yea, i've even tried setting it to 0 right before its used and the same problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your reinterpret_cast might be causing some problems. When you call pthread_create, you are passing in "this" which is a SpikePlot*, but inside networkThreadFunc, you are casting it to a TetrodePlot*.

Are SpikePlot and TetrodePlot related? This isn't called out in what you've posted.

Comment: oops... sorry it isn't that way in my code, I made a mistake when copy/pasting the code into SO  I've since fixed the code in the quesiton.